# HttpWebRequest and Cookie handling

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies, httpwebrequest

Sending cookie received from httpwebrequest is not giving correct result however if i copy paste cookie value from browser cookie than it returns correct result. why i am not getting result from httpwebrequest but works perfectly fine from browser?

```
CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

var targetUri = new Uri("URL1");
HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri);
myHttpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
myHttpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

//Get Response
HttpWebResponse myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

//Create Request
targetUri = new Uri("URL2");
myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(targetUri);
myHttpWebRequest.Method = "GET";
myHttpWebRequest.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

//Get Response
myHttpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse();

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myHttpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
{
   string html = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Following is second request(URL2) fiddler with cookie received through first request(URL1):

```
Request:
GET URL2 
HTTP/1.1
Host: www.xyz.com
Cookie: JSESSIONID=Mn7qJwrRnxLn1NNfT1PNr1L2Gr2KCkfFVCRS1wfsT4zfzWJhT62J!-876337174

Response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 27 Feb 2015 13:03:52 GMT
Content-Length: 13
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
```

Now if i copy paste first url(URL1) in browser and use cookie value from browser then it returns correct result:

```
Request:

GET URL2 
HTTP/1.1
Host: www.xyz.com
Cookie: JSESSIONID=PPPHJwmKQNh2ykVXytlcfTDH2YWNbtv76vPBzZTG3Dfdm9Mx0J74!-876337174

Response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 27 Feb 2015 13:06:15 GMT
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
Content-Length: 21417
```

Answer (score 0):

Weblogic is returning the cookies in the response, and you need to send it back in the next request.

```
cookieContainer.Add(response.Cookies);
```

(Your cookieContainer is on your machine and is empty).